# How to delete subscriptions with YouTube API v3 (Java)?

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

So I am trying to make a program that can automatically delete all channels that I subscribed to, but I ran in to an error that I cant solve..

I have this code (after having done the proper authentication):

```
Subscriptions subs = youtube.subscriptions();
    com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube.Subscriptions.List subscribers =subs.list("id").setMySubscribers(true);
    SubscriptionListResponse resp = subscribers.execute();

    for(Subscription s: resp.getItems()){
        System.out.println(s.getId());
        com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube.Subscriptions.Delete d = subs.delete(s.getId());
        d.execute();

    }
```

However, running this gives me this error:

[image: Error pic]

Tried the code to add a subscription from the YouTube tutorial and that works fine..

EDIT: the error comes from d.execute();

EDIT2: Also doing using the example of https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/delete (bottom of the page) to delete the subscription gives the same error

Comment: The error is quite self explanatory I think. *Permission denied* So you should start looking at where you define your user (credentials, potentially secret key and so on).

Comment: I looked there... I give the max authentication level possible..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that you're using `setMySubscribers(true)`, which will give you the list of subscriptions *to your channel*, not the list that your account is subscribed to. (And it makes sense that you can't delete subscriptions other people have made to your channel.) Instead, use `setMine(true)` to get your account's subscriptions.

```
Subscriptions subs = youtube.subscriptions();
com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube.Subscriptions.List subscribers =
    subs.list("id").setMine(true); // <- use setMine(), not setMySubscribers()
SubscriptionListResponse resp = subscribers.execute();
...
```

Comment: Aaaaah makes sense! Thanks, this solved the problem! :-)